# Vue3, Pinia - Component is not reactive

Tags: components, vuejs3, store, reactive, pinia

I have created a store with pinia. In this store I have an object named `assetGroups` as state.

```
state: () => ({
   assetGroups: AssetService.fetchAssetGroups(),
})
```

This object looks similar to the following (I have shortened the object, for simplicity)

```
groupKey1: {
    name: "My Group 1",
    assets: {
      assetKey1: {
        name: "My Asset 1"
      },
      assetKey2: {
        name: "My Asset 2"
      }
    }
}
```

In my `AssetList.vue` component I have imported and registered the store in the setup function

```
import { useAssetStore } from '@/stores/AssetStore'

setup() {
  const assetStore = useAssetStore()
  return { assetStore }
}
```

In the template I iterate over the `assetGroups`

```
<AssetGroup
    v-for="group in assetStore.assetGroups"
    :key="group.groupKey"
    :thisGroup="group"
/>
```

#### Until here, everything works fine

My goal is to remove an asset from this `assetGroups` state object. To achive this I wrote an action in my store named `removeSelectedAssets()`

```
removeSelectedAssets() {
    for (const [groupKey, assetGroup] of Object.entries(this.assetGroups)) {
          const assets = toRaw(assetGroup).assets
          for (const [assetKey, thisAsset] of Object.entries(assets)) {
               if (thisAsset.isSelected) {
                    delete toRaw(this.assetGroups)[groupKey]['assets'][assetKey]
               }
          }
     }
},
```

This is indeed removing the asset from the object, but it is not reactive.
I also tried using `storeToRefs`

```
const { assetGroups } = storeToRefs(assetStore)
```

But I was not able to get it working yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the reactive function from vue

```
state: () => ({
   assetGroups: reactive(AssetService.fetchAssetGroups()),
})
```

But it seems that nested objects generally won't be reactive.
When I wrap each object into a reactive() function itself, then it is working fine.
So in order to get it working I ended up splitting my object into an `assetListObject` and `groupListObject`

```
state: () => {
    return {
        groupListObject: reactive(AssetService.fetchGroupList()),
        assetListObject: reactive(AssetService.fetchAssetList()),
    }
},
```